# How to return in php DOMXPath object?

Tags: php, html, laravel, parsing, domxpath

Now found query if '$NotXP->query' = query return string?!

How to make work next code?

```
$xp = new \DOMXPath(@\DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile($url));

        $list = $xp->query('//table[@class="table-list quality series"] tbody');
        $link = $list->query('//tr[@class="item"]');

        $arr_links = [];

        foreach ($link as $link_in_cycle) {
            $link_quality = $link_in_cycle->query('//td[@class="column first video"]');
            $link_audio = $link_in_cycle->query('//td[@class="column audio"]');
            $link_size = $link_in_cycle->query('//td[@class="column size"]');
            $link_seed = $link_in_cycle->query('//td[@class="column seed-leech"] span[@class="seed"]');
            $link_download_url = $link_in_cycle->query('//td[@class="column last download"] a')->getAttribute("data-default");
```

---

html source for request @nigel-ren

From this code need grab of info

```
   <tbody>
                                      <tr class="item">
                <td class="column first video">720x400</td>
                <td class="column audio">mp3</td>
                <td class="column size">5.70 Gb</td>
                <td class="column seed-leech">
                    <span class="seed">15</span>
                    <span class="leech">26</span>
                </td>
                <td class="column updated">07.07.2017</td>
                <td class="column consistence"><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="title in td" data-type="torrent-consistence" class="show-modal show-consistence" data-route="/hashinfo/12345?fields=files"></a></td>
                <td class="column last download">
                <a class="button middle rounded download zona-link"
   data-type="download"
   data-zona="0"
   data-torrent=""
   data-default="url_data"
   data-not-installed=""
   data-installed=""
   data-metriks="{'eventType': 'click', 'data' : { 'type': 'show_download', 'id': '84358'}}"
   title="text in title" href="javascript:void(0);" >Download</a>                </td>
```

Comment: Can you show what you are trying to achieve, and possibly a sample url which people could use to test any possible solution.

Comment: @NigelRen, add html source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a few changes to help me in debug the code.  The main thing is that your XPath expressions were invalid, you can always try a site like [FreeFormatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) which allows you to check your expressions with some example source.

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xp = new \DOMXPath($doc);

$list = $xp->query('//table[@class="table-list quality series"]//tr[@class="item"]');
$arr_links = [];

foreach ($list as $link_in_cycle) {

    $link_quality = $xp->query('//td[@class="column first video"]/text()', $link_in_cycle)[0]->wholeText;
    $link_audio = $xp->query('//td[@class="column audio"]/text()', $link_in_cycle)[0]->wholeText;
    $link_size = $xp->query('//td[@class="column size"]/text()', $link_in_cycle)[0]->wholeText;
    $link_seed = $xp->query('//td[@class="column seed-leech"]//span[@class="seed"]/text()', $link_in_cycle)[0]->wholeText;
    $link_download_url = $xp->query('//td[@class="column last download"]//a/@data-default', $link_in_cycle)[0]->value;

    echo $link_quality.PHP_EOL;
    echo $link_audio.PHP_EOL;
    echo $link_size.PHP_EOL;
    echo $link_seed.PHP_EOL;
    echo $link_download_url.PHP_EOL;
}
```

The XPath expressions try and retrieve the text node in each element, which will return a list of all of the nodes, this code does assume there isn't any whitespace around the actual content (and uses [0] to fetch the first element of the list).  The `wholetext` is just the actual content of the DOMText element.

With the sample content you gave (plus the surrounding bits I had to invent) it gives...

```
720x400
mp3
5.70 Gb
15
Download
```

Comment: $link_download_url need artibute 'data-default'

Comment: I've changed the XPath to fetch the attribute.